# Mobile app in ionic framework

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework. I have SPA build in .net mvc, angularjs & web api which a large web application. But all form are simple data entry forms with input and dropdowns. I want to build simple mobile app for not all but some forms using the same web api. I have googled and found that Ionic framework can do the work, but where should I start from? Need guidance on what type of app (native,web or hybrid) will be best for my purpose. I am looking for these few features.

1. Should be available for android, iOS and windows download.
2. Should have push notification.
3. Update the app without uninstalling.
4. Performance

Answer (score 0):

Basically ionic use basic `html components + ionic components + angularjs` and that can be installed across iOS, Android, and Windows mobiles.

Also push notification also supported in ionic

updates are available without uninstall

and it gaves best performance for a small and basic functionality

now a days so many application build with hybrid platform like reactjs and ionic.

For your business purpose you can go with it definitely as it is a simple form submission and saves your time.

You can refer that links to see apps build with ionic framework:
http://showcase.ionicframework.com/apps/top